# Login with Django Rest Framework and Angular 2

Tags: django, angular, django-rest-framework

I'm new using `Angular 2` with `django restframework`.

How can I make a login and register page with those two?
Any tutorial to suggest?

I've been searching for tutorials but I did not find a good one.

Comment: Have you tried https://thinkster.io/ they have plenty of good real world projects/resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to write your own registration view but login is easy enough, depending on which authentication method you want to use, token authentication is like:

import auth views:

```
from rest_framework.authtoken import views
```

then define a url like:

```
url(r'^login/$', views.obtain_auth_token)
```

assuming you've properly generated tokens on sign up.  This info is all in the authentication section of the DRF docs.

If you're newer / unfamiliar with web security, maybe django-rest-auth or a similar plugin is the way to go for you.